# how to pass dynamic variable to limitTo filter in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="coursCmt in courArg.coursCmts"
        ng-init="userInfo(coursCmt)">

        <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-responsive user-photo"
                    ng-src="{{coursCmt.imagePath || 'defaultimage.png'}} ">
            </div>
            <!-- /thumbnail -->
        </div>
        <!-- /col-sm-1 -->

        <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-10" style="padding-left: 10px">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <strong>{{coursCmt.username}}</strong>
                </div>
                <div>{{coursCmt.cText}}</div>
                <!-- /panel-body -->

                <small><a style="color: #0088cc" >Mi piace</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a
                    class="risposta" style="color: #0088cc;"    ng-click="cmtText(coursCmt.cId,coursCmt)" >Rispondi</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<span
                    class="text-muted"> {{coursCmt.cWhen | date:'MMM d, y h:mm:ss a '}}</span></small><br>
                <strong><a id="quantity{{coursCmt.cId}}" style="color: #0088cc" ng-click="quantityfunct(coursCmt.cId)" ng-if ="coursCmt.replyCmts.length>1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span>Vedere tutte le {{coursCmt.replyCmts.length}} risposte </a></strong>
            </div>
            <!-- /panel panel-default -->

            <div class="row"  ng-repeat="replyCmt in coursCmt.replyCmts |orderBy : '-cWhen' | limitTo:quantity{{coursCmt.cId}}"
                ng-init="userReplyInfo(replyCmt)" style="padding-left: 40px">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
                    <div class="thumbnail" style="max-width: 70%; max-height: 70%">
                        <img class="img-responsive user-photo"
                            ng-src="{{replyCmt.imagePath || 'defaultimage.png'}}">
                    </div>
                    <!-- /thumbnail -->
                </div>
                <!-- /col-sm-1 -->

                <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-10" style="padding-left: 0px">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <strong>{{replyCmt.username}}</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div>{{replyCmt.cText}}</div>
                        <!-- /panel-body -->
                        <small> <a style="color: #0088cc">Mi piace</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
                            <span class="text-muted">{{replyCmt.cWhen | date:'MMM d,y h:mm:ss a'}}</span></small>
                    </div>

                    <!-- /panel panel-default -->
                </div>

            </div>
            <strong><a ng-hide="myValue{{coursCmt.cId}}" id="quantity1{{coursCmt.cId}}" style="color: #0088cc" ng-click="quantityback(coursCmt)">Ridure</a></strong>
            <div id="message{{coursCmt.cId}}" style="display:none">


                <div class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2" >
                    <img
                        ng-src="{{profileImagePath || 'defaultimage.png'}} " style="max-width: 60%; max-height: 60%">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-11 col-xs-10">
                    <textarea ng-model="creplyText" class="form-control" rows="1"
                         style=" width: 95%" ng-enter="saveReplyCmt(creplyText,coursCmt.cId,coursCmt.coursArgsId,coursCmt.userId,user.id)"></textarea>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- /col-sm-5 -->
    </div>


    <!-- /row -->

</div>
<script>

        $scope.quantityfunct = function(coursCmt){
            $("#quantity"+coursCmt.cId).hide();
            $("#quantity1"+coursCmt.cId).show();
            $scope["myValue"+coursCmt.cId] = false;
            $scope["quantity"+coursCmt.cId] ='';
        }

        $scope.quantityback = function(coursCmt){
            $("#quantity1"+coursCmt.cId).hide();
            $("#quantity"+coursCmt.cId).show();
            $scope["myValue"+coursCmt.cId] = true;
            $scope["quantity"+coursCmt.cId] = 1;
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the moustaches like this

```
   ng-repeat="replyCmt in coursCmt.replyCmts |orderBy : '-cWhen' | limitTo:coursCmt.cId"
```

Comment: coursCmt.cId is ID of coursCmt object .....i just need to change limitation just one by one